# Changing RichtextToolbar.java using GWT

Tags: java, gwt, toolbar

I am working on a project that had already been developed using GWT. I just want to make minor style changes to display a nicer toolbar. So I found a code at the following link : http://blog.elitecoderz.net/gwt-toolbar-for-richtextarea-a-richtexttoolbar-with-html-editor/2010/02/

I then understood that to be able to implement this new code, I had to download GWT. This is what I did. But I don't know anything about java or GWT. My php and HTML files are running on MAMP and they are stored on a mysite directory. Among these files, I have a java directory with a RichTextToolbar.java file to which I want to make some changes. What am I supposed to do with this file?

As little as I understood, I must create a GWT project with Eclipse, taking the only RichTextToolbar.java file, run and compile it and then I should have some new compiled files, that I must import back in my mysite directory? Am I right?

Comment: So are you asking how to compile a single GWT widget and then add its functionality into an existing website?

Answer (score 3):

You must recompile full GWT project,if want see the changes, because GWT compile Java to JavaScript and dont use *.java resources files.